# Can i move or translate() pseudo element (::after, ::before) under a text on hover?

Tags: css, animation, pseudo-element

I'm trying to translateX() a 'dot' under a text from one end to another, but just across the width of the text.

Here's what I've tried, but it doesn't work. Have you any solutions to that?

```
.wrapper ul li a::before{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  height: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.wrapper ul li a:hover::before{
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent div position relative to see the dot
You need to make a tag to position relative

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I've used animation + @keyframes to transision the pseudo element. Here's how.

```
.wrapper ul li a::before{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  height: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
.wrapper ul li a:hover::before{
  transform: scale(1);
  left: 100%; 
  animation: transition 1s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes transition {
  0% {left:0;}
  20% {left:20%;}
  30% {left:30%;}
  45% {left:45%;}
  65% {left:65%}
  75% {left:75%}
  90% {left:90%}
  100% {left:100%}
}
```